# Output numbers with comma separation in snowflake result set

Tags: sql, configuration, format, resultset, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**I'm working with SQL queries in Snowflake.** I'm able to work in the browser (chrome), or on SQLWorkbenchJ. I'm comfortable with both, but prefer the browser.

I'm working with moderately large numbers, up into the hundreds of billions (10^8), so it would be really helpful if I could **make the program print my numbers with comma separation** for the thousands (e.g. 12,345,678,901.00 vs. 12345678901.00).

I've looked into the documentation on format models here 
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql-format-models.html
but I can't see an option to output in the style I'm looking for.

Even besides that, I would really prefer to **implement this as a configuration to the interface** itself rather than code I apply to my queries.

Comment: It is probably like Oracle, where you have to do something like `'###,###,###,##0.00'`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [numeric format models](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql-format-models.html#numeric-format-models) appears to cover your need via the `9` (nine), `,` (comma), and `.` (period) symbols. Quoting some relevant portions from the documentation:

> `9`: Position for a digit; leading/trailing zeros are replaced with blank spaces.
>
> `0`: Position for a digit; leading/trailing zeros are explicitly printed.
>
> `.` (period): Decimal fraction separator; always printed as a period.
>
> `,` (comma): Digit group separator; printed as a comma or blank space.
>
> [...]
>
> The digit group separator `,` (comma) or `G` results in the corresponding group separator character being printed if the number is big enough so the digits are on the both sides of group separator. An example of a format model useful for printing currency sums would be 999,999.00.

Here are some adapted examples demonstrating the required format:

```sql
SELECT to_varchar(123.21, '999,999,999,999.00');
SELECT to_varchar(12345.00, '999,999,999,999.00');
SELECT to_varchar(12345678, '999,999,999,999.00');
SELECT to_varchar(12345678901, '999,999,999,999.00');
SELECT to_varchar(12345678901.59, '999,999,999,999.00');
```

Answer (score 11):

Looks like your wish has been partially granted!

In Snowflake's new web interface (they call it [Snowsight](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-snowsight.html)), you can choose to display numbers using commas as the separator for thousands.

It only affects the display in the UI though - it doesn't work for exporting data (which shouldn't be a problem, because exported data shouldn't be formatted - that's something excel or other can take care of).

[image]

Comment: do you know if there is any way to turn this off? it's driving me crazy when I want to quickly copy and paste a number from Snowsight and it has commas

Comment: Just click to activate/deactivate each feature.